# Not Found: /nurse/articles/10/ Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have started learning Django rest Framework.I read an article and tried on my computer.But unable to figure out why am i getting this error.
Some one please help me.Thank you

```
models.py

class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
  email = models.EmailField()

  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.name)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')

    def __str__(self):
      return str(self.title)

views.py

class ArticleView(APIView):
    def get(self, request,pk=None):
        try:
            if pk:
                allowance=get_object_or_404(Article.objects.all(),pk=pk)
                print(allowance)
                serializer = ArticleSerializer(allowance,many=True)
                return Response({serializer.data})
            else:
                 articles = Article.objects.all()
                 serializer = ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True)
                 return Response({"articles": serializer.data})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response({"success":False,"message":str(e)},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    def post(self, request):
        try:
            article = request.data.get('article')
            print('Data',article)
            # Create an article from the above data
            serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=article)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                article_saved = serializer.save()
            return Response({"success": "Article '{}' created successfully".format(article_saved.title)})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response({"success":False,"message":str(e)},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    def put(self, request, pk):
            saved_article = get_object_or_404(Article.objects.all(), pk=pk)
            data = request.data.get('article')
            serializer = ArticleSerializer(instance=saved_article, data=data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                article_saved = serializer.save()
            return Response({"success": "Article '{}' updated successfully".format(article_saved.title)})

    def delete(self, request, pk):
            # Get object with this pk
            article = get_object_or_404(Article.objects.all(), pk=pk)
            article.delete()
            return Response({"message": "Article with id `{}` has been deleted.".format(pk)},status=204)

serializers.py

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # class Meta:
    #     model = Article
    #     fields = ('title', 'description', 'body', 'author_id')
    title = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()
    body = serializers.CharField()
    author_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Article.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.body = validated_data.get('body', instance.body)
        instance.author_id = validated_data.get('author_id', instance.author_id)

        instance.save()
        return instance
    
urls.py

from django.urls import path

from .views import ArticleView
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router=DefaultRouter()
app_name = "articles"

# app_name will help us do a reverse look-up latter.
urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/', ArticleView.as_view()),
    path('articles/<int:pk>', ArticleView.as_view())
]
```

while hitting get in postman i am getting all my articles,but when i try to fetch by using primary key ,id shows not found error.

Comment: update `'articles/<int:pk>` to `'articles/<int:pk>/` (ends with slash)in your `urls.py`

Comment: thanks @ArakkalAbu,

Comment: why am i getting Article object is not iterable,while fetching using pk?

Comment: please show the error

Comment: {
    "success": false,
    "message": "'Article' object is not iterable"
}